# Can't find ProjectName-swift.h

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

It works for one target but not the other. I have looked at build settings to see where this file is set but I can't find it.

```
#import "Wunder-Swift.h"
```

This gets me the error "file not found". I have no idea where to set this.

Comment: Please have look at the similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328034/importing-project-swift-h-into-a-objective-c-class-file-not-found

Comment: It says In your case, you have to add this line in the *.m file:

#import <NewTestApp/NewTestApp-Swift.h> I have import in .m file so when I do this it doesn't work for either target. when I do the above it works for one target but not the other

Comment: If you are using your swift code inside objective-c file then import to *.m file. If your swift code is in inside some module then like #import <NewTestApp/NewTestApp-Swift.h> otherwise #import <NewTestApp-Swift.h>

Answer (score -1):

Wunder-Swift.h file can be found in Target -> Build Settings -> Objective-c Bridging Header.

Or you can search for "swift", it will show you.

If Wunder-Swift.h is not added in your project then just add a new Objective-C file, it will show an option to add a Bridging-Header file and automatically set your bridge file path.

Comment: The poster is asking about the generated interface header, not the bridging header.