# Not able to import "project-name-Swift.h" file xcode

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

I have 2 files.

1. "CodeInjection.m"

   ```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #import "BiplovCodeInjection-Swift.h"

   @interface CodeInjection: NSObject
   @end

   @implementation CodeInjection

   static void __attribute__((constructor)) initialize(void){
       NSLog(@"==== Code Injection in Action==== with sniffer");
       [[CodeInjectionSwift shared] performTask];
   }

   @end
   ```

My second file is.

```
"BiplovCodeInjectionSwift.swift"

import Foundation
import NetworkInterceptor

@objc class CodeInjectionSwift: NSObject {
    @objc public static let shared = CodeInjectionSwift()

    override private init(){}

    @objc func performTask(){
        let requestSniffers: [RequestSniffer] = [
            RequestSniffer(requestEvaluator: AnyHttpRequestEvaluator(), handlers: [
                SniffableRequestHandlerRegistrable.console(logginMode: .nslog).requestHandler()
                ])
        ]

        let requestRedirectors: [RequestRedirector] = [
            RequestRedirector(requestEvaluator: DomainHttpRequestEvaluator(domain: "www.antennahouse.com"), redirectableRequestHandler: AlternateUrlRequestRedirector(url: URL(string: "https://www.rhodeshouse.ox.ac.uk/media/1002/sample-pdf-file.pdf")!))
        ]

        let networkConfig = NetworkInterceptorConfig(requestSniffers: requestSniffers,
                                                     requestRedirectors: requestRedirectors)
        NetworkInterceptor.shared.setup(config: networkConfig)
        NetworkInterceptor.shared.startRecording()
    }
}
```

It fails on the line `"#import "BiplovCodeInjection-Swift.h"`

I built a new project > framework.

Here's my file strucuture

[image]

Why is it that I can't import the header file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing Project-Swift.h into a Objective-C class...file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328034/importing-project-swift-h-into-a-objective-c-class-file-not-found)