# Importing Project-Swift.h into a Objective-C class of .mm ->Cannot find interface

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, xcode, bridge

I am able to access swift function in Objective c classes i.e. "*.m" file using suggestion given in [Importing Project-Swift.h into a Objective-C class...file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328034/importing-project-swift-h-into-a-objective-c-class-file-not-found).

I want to use cpp function in objectvie c class file. To do so I have converted "*.m" file to "*.mm" . Now I am facing issue to access swift classes in .mm file. I am getting "Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIResponder', superclass of 'AppDelegate'" error for all swift classes in "Project-swift.h" file. please check attachment :
[image]
Anyone has any solution for accessing cpp file and swift class in objective c file?

Comment: You don't have to convert all .m files to .mm. Could you please add an example of a C++ function that you want to use in Objective-C?

Comment: e.g. std::shared_ptr of cpp i want to use in objectiveC code. And from Objective c class i want to access swift functions

Comment: Do you want to declare an Objective-C class with a `std::shared_ptr` property?

Comment: Well, at least on simple project I did not see any problems. Probably it depends on order... I created main iOS single view Objective-C project, added Swift file, so converted into bridged environment, created simple Swift class, integrated it in AppDelegate.m, build & run, then renamed AppDelegate.m into .mm, added cpp code in one line with swift call, build & run. Everything is ok.