# pod spec lint command fails due to project-Swift.h

Tags: swift, objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods

I am building an objective C framework with some swift files in it, and I want to create a pod. When I am using command pod spec link I get an error that says

- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.

and I noticed that the is is a NOTE logged that says

fatal error: 'project/project-Swift.h' file not found

Xcoce builds normally the project but as I understand the xcodebuild command that runs through pod spec lint can not find the auto generated header.

Any thoughts? Do the other warnings of the code make xcodebuild to fail compilation and so the auto generated header is not getting created?

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328034/importing-project-swift-h-into-a-objective-c-class-file-not-found#:~:text=If%20you%20can%20not%20find,will%20Xcode%20generate%20this%20file) stack overflow question?

Comment: Actually i hadn't included my swift files in spec.source inside podspec, that was the problem