# Problems accessing certain types in NSObject subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, subclass, nsobject

In the past I have created subclasses of NSObject and return various types from strings to UIColor's.

Here is an example piece of code:

[image]

However I recently started a new project in iOS 8 and have gone to do the same thing but I am getting the following error:

[image]

I am able to return NSString's, NSDictionary's, etc but am unable to return things that are UI based. So UIColor, UITabBar, etc.

The first project was created before updating to Xcode 6 and the second one (one with issue) was created after upgrading. Both are using Objective C.

I can't see any difference between the 2 files. Does anyone know why I might be experiencing this issue?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add on top

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

That's because `UIColor` is class from UIKit framework, so you need to import UIKit as well.

*So why this error occurred from Xcode 6 ?*
Because Apple has removed PCH default support, refer to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034161/did-the-way-how-to-globally-import-files-change-in-xcode-6-ios-8/27034234#27034234)

Comment: Hi l0gg3r, thanks for the response. So does that mean we should handle creating helper classes differently? Or is it still best to subclass NSObject and then add the import if we need to return any UI elements?

Comment: Hi, the best practice is to add `@class UIColor;` on top of the .h file, and `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` in .m file

Comment: So they removed it to make apps compile longer so people switch to Swift?