# I want to include BluetoothManager framework in swift or objective-c, having problems

Tags: objective-c, swift, header, iphone-privateapi

I am having problems including frameworks in my project.

I have downloaded the private APIs from https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks 
This gives me header files to use with the framework already in xcode as I understand it.
I have added the header files to the framework folder in xcode for bluetoothmanager.
I have also included this framework in xcode.
[image: paths for adding framework]

The "framework search paths" is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Develop­er/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer­/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Privat­eFrameworks
```

Here is a picture of my xcode folder structure:
[image: This is in project root as you can see]

When I try to include the header file i get the error "BluetoothManager/BluetoothManager.h file not found".

Here is the code for that:

```
#include <BluetoothManager/BluetoothManager.h>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C has this in common with C/C++; the quoted form is for "local" includes of files (you need to specify the relative path from the current file, e.g. `#include "headers/my_header.h"`), while the angle-bracket form is for "global" includes -- those found somewhere on the include path passed to the compiler (e.g. `#include <math.h>`).

So to have your own headers use < > not " " you need to pass either the relative or the absolute path for your header directory to the compiler.

Comment: Thanks! I will check when I get back to work on monday!

Comment: The weird thing is that I still cannot find it.. I have included the correct path. I include in code with #import <BluetoothManager/BluetoothManager.h>. 
- error can't find file....

Comment: Ok I solved it. I am using a bridging header since im writing in swift and wanted to import objective-c headers. Now the problem has become that my header files in the framework gives alot of errors. Something like xcode tries to compile using swift on the objective-c headers..?

Comment: What's not yet clear it is, if you want to import `Obj-c to Swift` or `Swift to Obj-c`?. If the import is from Obj-C Swift steps you should llebar out they are: 1. Create a `Header.h` comprehensive file containing all frameworks and / or files written in Obj-c and add the file `Header.h` a project settings. If you have questions on how to do I recommend this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062618/swift-to-objective-c-header-not-created-in-xcode-6).