# An Objective-C category for an existing Swift class

Tags: objective-c, swift, interop

I would like create an objective-C category for an Swift existing Class:
`Creation.swift` with its category `Creation+Additions.m`

I have needed an Obj-C because I have to use a C method. C and Swift together : Oh Dear ! ...

My issue : I have used a dynamic framework in which Objective-C and Swift cohabit. I have got an umbrella header for the bridging Obj-C and Swift.

However, for my category's header  `Creation+Additions.m`, the header AppCreationKit-Swift.swift` is not found.

[image: Issue]

Comment: Possibly add your objective-c category method in bridging header.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift to Objective-C header not created in Xcode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062618/swift-to-objective-c-header-not-created-in-xcode-6) (is your Swift class marked as `@objc`?)

Comment: @Rajesh Maurya : It's a dynamic framework so there isn't  a brindging header but an umbrella header. And, I have already add my  objective-c category method in header : the header AppCreationKit-Swift.swift` is not found. Thx for your answer :)

Comment: @ nhgrif : I have seen this post. I have already carried out their answers. The fact that I use a dynamic framework without brindging header renders my case more specific.

Comment: The swift compiler does not allow you to do this. I'm afraid it is not possible to have an objectiveC category for a swift class.