# Writing tests for swift classes with XCTest written in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift, unit-testing

I'm facing a problem trying to write a test for class written in Objective-c and gets injected with a class written in Swift.

Example in the Test file:

```
SomeSwiftClass *swiftVar = [SomeSwiftClass new];
SomeObjectiveCClass *objVar = [[SomeObjectiveCClass alloc] initWithSwiftClass:swiftVar]
```

But the complier doesn't recognize the Swift class, and it doesnt support importing the "Target-Swift.h" too..

How can I write a test for both Objective c and Swift at the same TestFile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few things that need to be in place if you want to use a Swift class in Objective-C.

- The bridging header is required "Target-Bridging-Header.h"
- Precede the class definition with `@objc` in the .swift file.
- If you're still stuck, try deleting your .swift files and adding them to the project again, and Xcode will ask to generate the bridging header for you.
- Check out the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID138
- Or this link:
  [Swift to Objective-C header not created in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062618/swift-to-objective-c-header-not-created-in-xcode-6?rq=1)

I managed to get it working, so if you post more of your code or share what you're doing I might be able to help.