# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'WCSessionDelegate'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchos-2, watchos

I am new to iOS development. I created a swift class as follows:

```
import WatchConnectivity;
import HealthKit;
@objc class Blah : NSObject, WCSessionDelegate { 
...
}
```

I need @objc so that I could use this class from objective-C (that already exists). The problem is that when the compiler creates bridge [productName]-Swift.h, it complains that it cannot find WCSessionDelegate. Exact error:

*Cannot find protocol declaration for 'WCSessionDelegate'; did you mean 'NSURLSessionDelegate'?*

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8test8Blah")
@interface  Blah: NSObject <WCSessionDelegate>
```

Instead of implementing that delegate, if I change it to the following, it works.

```
@objc class Blah : NSObject {
  ...
  func setSessionDelegate(delegate:WCSessionDelegate) -> Blah {
    self.mDelegate = delegate;
    return(self)
  }
}
```

I prefer the former way. How do I resolve this compilation error? Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `[productName]-Swift.h` file only adds the include if mosules are supported:

```
#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(modules)
@import ObjectiveC;
@import WatchConnectivity;
@import Foundation;
#endif
```

In my case, and probably in yours too, they are disabled. If you can't or won't enable them, you can just make sure to include the connectivity header yourself each time, e.g.

```
#import <WatchConnectivity/WatchConnectivity.h>
#import "MyApp-Swift.h"
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24064015/67824